# how can i navigate between views and pass a model in view without getting error in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, post

i have a MvcApplication for Store WebSite and i want when user go to Products and when click on Buy for each of product,go to a view that will reviews Buy List and make sure's user are accepted,then after user clicked on IAccept return to Index View with a Message
now my problem is this,i can't use passed product object in my View,error message is this:"@Model.name is null"
here is my Product,Buy ActionResult and Buy,Product View

```
    public ActionResult Product() 
    {       
        var pmodel = db.posts.ToList();
        product pro = new product()
                qrcode = 2455174,
                name = "hub",
                color_id = 3,
                category_id = 3,
                price = 10,
                maker_code = 1,
                offer_id = 0
            };
            db.products.Add(pro);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (pmodel != null)
        {
            return View(pmodel);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Product View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.post>
   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Product";
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";
    }

     <h3>Products</h3>
     <html>
     <head><title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function enlarge(el) {
        if (el.width = 300)
        {
        el.width = 50;
        el.height = 50;
        }
     el.width = 300;
     el.height = 240;
     }
   </script>
   </head>
  <body>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
        Image:
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
        Name:
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
        Description:
    </td>
</tr>
@foreach(var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
       <img src="~/Resources/image_2.jpg") id="x" 
       width="50" height="50" onclick="enlarge(this)"
                 alt="Click To See Image Larger">
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text)
    </td>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm()){
        <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Buy Now!", "Buy")
        </p>
        }
    </td>
 </tr>
 }
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Buy ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buy(user users,product products,post p) 
    {
        var prod = db.products.Single(pro => pro.qrcode == products.qrcode);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        factor fact = new factor() {description=p.text,factor_id=products.qrcode,count=1
            ,product_name=products.name,product_qrcode=products.qrcode,status=
            "Buy with Balance fFunds",date=date.ToString()};
        return View(prod);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Buy(product products) 
    {
        return View(products);
    }
```

And Here is Buy View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.product
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Buy";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";
}

<h2>Review</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Are you sure to buy this stuff?</legend>
</fieldset>
    <div class="display">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
<div class="display">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price)
    </div>
<div class="display">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.qrcode)
    </div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Accept" />    
</p>
}
```

my problem summary is,when user go to products and see the products post's and try to buy something (by clicking on "Buy Now!" link)then will be Redirect to Buy View,then user must reviews and Accept stuff details then Redirect to Index with a Message from complete operation or something like that!!But it doesn't show stuff details.

Comment: i have problem with passing a model object to view,but thanks

Comment: Sorry the question is a bit confusing. But Ill try. You will need to do a `ActionLink` into the controller like you do for when you click on buy. But then instead of `return View();`, you can do something like `return Redirect("~/Home/Index");` or `return View("SomeVeiwInCurrentController");`does that work or is it something else that you are expecting?

Comment: With `return View(View,Model)` you can pass a model in.

Comment: it's true but i'm doing this return View(products); in my ActionResult and when i run the program,compiler give me error in the Buy view which is review the buy list.@Model.name is null!